# Rotar Texto Y Mostrar Menú Con Css

Tags: html, css

Mis objetivos aquí son 3:

- Rotar o transformar el "+" en una cruz
- Desplegar un menú centrado al pasar el ratón sobre el "+" bajo la caja, los 4 en la misma línea: Link1/Link2/Link3/Link4. Y que no desaparezcan al quitar el ratón de encima de la caja sino al quitarlo del área de la línea de links + la caja
- Que al reducirse la pantalla de 600px esta función la realice al hacer clic.

```css
body{ height:1000px;}
#header{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:1000;
 top:5px;
 padding-left:15px;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 padding-right:15px;
 border:black solid 1px;
 margin:0;
 left:0;
 text-align:center;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-17px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 line-height:0px;
 }
#header:hover {border:none;
}
#menu{display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
+
  <div id="menu">
   <a href="#"> Link 1</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 2</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 4</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Donde está el menú y los demás links? Agrega el ejemplo completo

Comment: Hecho @devconcept

Comment: ¿Podrías claificar un poco lo del "+" y la cruz? No me termina de quedar claro

Comment: ¿Tienes que mantener esa estructura HTML?¿Y ese CSS? Para hacer lo que pides, reescribiría casi todo lo que tienes :$

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @AlvaroMontoro. Para la animación del `+` podrías usar `rotate(45deg)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que quieres es algo complicado pero aquí tienes una solución de CSS puro.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 5px;
  padding: 20px 15px 15px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -17px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0px;
}
#header:hover {
  border: solid 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
}
.menu li {
  color: white;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  border-bottom: white solid 1px;
}
#header:hover .menu {
  display: none;
}
#header .cross {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 15px;
  left: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
#header:hover .cross {
  transform: none;
}
#header input[type='checkbox']:checked + .cross {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
#header input[type='checkbox']:checked + .cross + .menu {
  display: block
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #header:hover {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
  }
  #header:hover .menu {
    display: block
  }
  #header:hover .cross {
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="cross">
    +
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a>Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Link4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

La razón por la que es complicado en css es que para hacer un toggle tienes que usar un input de tipo `checkbox` y la pseudoclase `:checked` ya que uno de tus requerimientos es que se activase con click.

Estos elementos son un poco difíciles de estilar así que la solución más rápida y simple es cubrirlos con otro elemento y hacer que el `click` pase "a través" de él con `pointer-events: none`

Tuve que cambiar un poco la estructura ya que de lo contrario sería imposible lograrlo sin javascript.

Comment: Genial por hacerlo sólo con HTML y CSS. Se me pasó la parte de "con CSS" y me salté a JavaScript. Tendré que actualizar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a ir desde cero e, incrementalmente, explicando y añadiendo poco a poco lo que pides.

**Rotar o transformar el "+" en una cruz**

Esto lo puedes hacer bien con texto o bien con las pseudo-clases `::before` y `::after`. Elijas el método que elijas, el texto que rota debe ir en su propio elemento (porque si no, acabarías rotando todo: texto, caja y menú).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo se haría con texto:

```css
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  left:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transition:border 0.2s;
}

#header .aspa {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

#header:hover {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

#header:hover .aspa {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="aspa">+</div>
</div>
```

Si lo que buscas es tener una animación más elaborada, personalmente optaría por el método de las pseudo-clases: te da más control al poder animarlas individualmente y con diferentes estilos.

---

**Desplegar un menú centrado al pasar el ratón sobre el "+" bajo la caja, los 4 en la misma línea: Link1/Link2/Link3/Link4. Y que no desaparezcan al quitar el ratón de encima de la caja sino al quitarlo del área de la línea de links + la caja**

Esto es relativamente simple: añade la caja con el menú, ponle `display:none` y cuando se pase el menú por encima de la cruz, que se cambia a `display:block`. Para centrarlo, dale un año definido y ponle un `margin-left` negativo de la mitad del ancho (+ la mitad del cuadrado, para que se quede centrado con respecto al mismo).

El código sería así:

```css
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  left:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transition:border 0.2s;
}

#header .aspa {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

#header:hover {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

#header:hover .aspa {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

#menu {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-80px;
}

#header:hover #menu {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="aspa">+</div>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#"> Link 1</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 2</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 4</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Que al reducirse la pantalla de 600px esta función la realice al hacer clic**

Versión nueva del tercer paso: usando exclusivamente CSS y HTML.

```css
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  left:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transition:border 0.2s;
}

#header input {
  display:none;
}

#header .aspa {
  display:block;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

#aspabox:checked ~ #header {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

#aspabox:checked ~ #header .aspa {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

#menu {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-80px;
}

input:checked ~ #header #menu {
  display:block;
}

/* hover solo se aplicara cuando el ancho sea 600px o mas */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #header:hover {
    border:1px solid transparent;
  }

  #header:hover .aspa {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }

  #header:hover #menu {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="aspabox" />
<div id="header">
  <label class="aspa" for="aspabox">+</label>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#"> Link 1</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 2</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 4</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Versión anterior del tercer paso: usa JavaScript - Para esto vas a necesitar dos cosas: JavaScript y `@media` queries (aunque se podría hacer sólo con JavaScript). La idea es crear una clase que realice lo mismo que el `:hover` y hacer que el `:hover` sólo se aplique para resoluciones mayores que 600px. Entonces con JavaScript le añadirías o quitarías esa clase.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector("#header").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.className == "active") {
    this.className = "";
  } else {
    this.className = "active";
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  left:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transition:border 0.2s;
}

#header .aspa {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

#header.active {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

#header.active .aspa {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

#menu {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-80px;
}

#header.active #menu {
  display:block;
}

/* hover solo se aplicara cuando el ancho sea 600px o mas */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #header:hover {
    border:1px solid transparent;
  }

  #header:hover .aspa {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
  }

  #header:hover #menu {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="aspa">+</div>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#"> Link 1</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 2</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#"> Link 4</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Para ver cómo el hover no funciona en pantallas de menos de 600px deberás pulsar el botón de "Pantalla completa" y entonces cambiar el tamaño de la ventana a algo menor de 600px.